# Error : Value does not fall within the expected range in delete query?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a execute sql task which insert data into a table, but before that I need to make sure no data is available for particular date. we have a table where we are defining date for which date we want to data, and we are fetching that particular date using ssis variable 'Date'. today I was trying to load data dor '2015-05-10'. But it gave me error like '[Execute SQL Task] Error: "Value does not fall within the expected range.'. Below are the my execute sql task query:

```
delete from STG_Shipped_Invoiced
where Transaction_Date=?


INSERT INTO STG_Shipped_Invoiced (div_Code, inv_inv_id, tot_Net_Amt, 
trans_date, trans_type, Created_date, Transaction_Date)
select inv.DIV_CODE as Div_Code, inv.INV_ID as inv_inv_id, inv.TOT_NET_AMT as Tot_Net_Amt,
inv.TRANS_DATE as trans_date, inv.TRANS_TYPE as trans_type,  Getdate() as Created_date, 
CONVERT(DATE,inv.TRANS_DATE) as Transaction_Date 
from inv inv 
where CONVERT(DATE,inv.TRANS_DATE)=? and inv.TRANS_TYPE<>'CM' 
And inv.INV_ID in (select distinct INV_ID from inv_shp inv_ship where WHSE_CODE='WPP')
order by 1 asc, 2 asc


SELECT @@ROWCOUNT as NoOfRecords
```

Here I have defined a variable 'Date', where we are passing the date. Am i doing anything wrong with the delete query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this error in the past when unintentionally trying to populate multiple values into a parameter that expects only one.  Your script is applying "?" twice, but according to your description, you are only passing to it one parameter, which is the variable "Date".  Look at the Parameter Mapping in the SQL Task Editor.  The expected range error may be due to this inconsistency.

1. You could change the SQL to a stored procedure in which ? is passed to it once as a single argument or

   EXEC dbo.mystoredprocedure ?
2. Modify the current SQL so that ? is set equal to a new variable @Date.  Then within your current SQL replace ? with @Date.  This way it is passed only once.

```
DECLARE @Date DateTime
SET @DATE = ?
```

`DELETE FROM STG_Shipped_Invoiced
WHERE Transaction_Date=@Date

INSERT INTO STG_Shipped_Invoiced (
    div_Code, inv_inv_id, 
    tot_Net_Amt, 
    trans_date, 
    trans_type, 
    Created_date, 
    Transaction_Date)
SELECT 
    inv.DIV_CODE as Div_Code, 
    inv.INV_ID as inv_inv_id, 
    inv.TOT_NET_AMT as Tot_Net_Amt,
    inv.TRANS_DATE as trans_date, 
    inv.TRANS_TYPE as trans_type,  
    Getdate() as Created_date, 
    CONVERT(DATE,inv.TRANS_DATE) as Transaction_Date 
FROM inv inv 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,inv.TRANS_DATE)=@Date 
    AND inv.TRANS_TYPE<>'CM' 
    AND inv.INV_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT INV_ID 
                       FROM inv_shp inv_ship 
                       WHERE WHSE_CODE='WPP')
ORDER BY 1 asc, 2 asc

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT as NoOfRecords`

Right now your SQL script is looking for two parameters and only one is being supplied.  The third option is to define the Date variable twice in the Parameter Mappings for two different parameters, which avoids having to modify your current SQL.

My personal recommendation is to convert your SQL to a stored procedure and apply the stored procedure instead.  This way, later after the SSIS package is deployed you can update the SQL in the stored procedure without having to update the package.

Comment: Thanks user3662215,
                                     Your explanation really worked for me. I tried with stored procedure (your 1st suggestion) as you told to do so. Thanks for your valuable time.